# Carriage returns are ignored even by Notepad

Tags: csv, vb6, notepad

There is a function that runs as a scheduled task every day importing text from a text file:

```
Public Function ImportPersons(ByVal strImportFile As String) As Variant
Dim intFile As Integer, strRecord As String, strFields() As String
Dim lngReadCount As Long, blnChanged As Boolean

On Error GoTo GenErr:
    intFile = FreeFile
    Open strImportFile For Input As #intFile
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    DoEvents
    Do While Not EOF(intFile)
        Line Input #intFile, strRecord
        lngReadCount = lngReadCount + 1
        If strRecord <> "" Then
            If InStr(strRecord, "|") > 0 Then
                strFields = Split(strRecord, "|")
            Else
                strFields = Split(strRecord, ",")
            End If
            blnChanged = False
            If Trim(strFields(3)) <= " " Then  ' otherwise this is a company name entry and there are no person details
                rs.Open "Select * from dbPerson where Reference = '" & strFields(0) & "'", objCon.ActiveCon, adOpenStatic, adLockPessimistic
                If rs.EOF Then
                    rs.AddNew
                    rs("Reference") = Trim(strFields(0))
                    rs("FirstNames") = Trim(strFields(1))
                    rs("Surname") = Trim(strFields(2))
                    rs("DateOfBirth") = strFields(4)
                    rs("Height") = strFields(6)
                    rs("Mobile") = Trim(strFields(7))
                    rs("PNCID") = Trim(strFields(5))
                    rs("LastUpdated") = Now
                    rs.Update
                Else
                    If rs("FirstNames") <> Trim(strFields(1)) Then
                        rs("FirstNames") = Trim(strFields(1))
                        blnChanged = True
                    End If
                    If rs("Surname") <> Trim(strFields(2)) Then
                        rs("Surname") = Trim(strFields(2))
                        blnChanged = True
                    End If
                    If rs("DateOfBirth") <> strFields(4) Then
                        rs("DateOfBirth") = strFields(4)
                        blnChanged = True
                    End If
                    If rs("Height") <> strFields(6) Then
                        rs("Height") = strFields(6)
                        blnChanged = True
                    End If
                    If rs("Mobile") <> Trim(strFields(7)) Then
                        rs("Mobile") = Trim(strFields(7))
                        blnChanged = True
                    End If
                    If rs("PNCID") <> Trim(strFields(5)) Then
                        rs("PNCID") = Trim(strFields(5))
                        blnChanged = True
                    End If
                    If blnChanged Then
                        rs("LastUpdated") = Now
                        rs.Update
                    End If
                End If
                rs.Close
            End If
        End If
    Loop
    Close #intFile

    ImportPersons = "Total: " & lngReadCount

    Exit Function
GenErr:
    WriteError Err, Error$ & " in ImportPersons.", strErrorLog
    ImportPersons = Error$
    Exit Function
    Resume

End Function
```

Here is some sample data (it is not real data):

```
11123455|Super|Woman||14/07/1962|02/111/111|L765|01110101010
```

The scheduled task reported that there was one row in the text file this morning (there is usually about 50,000).  I have stepped through the code and it appears that VB6 is ignoring carriage returns.

I have opened the file using Notepad and I can see that there are no carriage returns.  When I open the file using textpad, I can see the carriage returns.  What is the problem?

Comment: My guess is that the file is using `\n` (UNIX-style) line breaks. Notepad will only display line breaks if they're Windows-style `\r\n`, but most other text editors are smart enough to use `\n` for line breaks if there aren't any `\r\n` in the file. I suspect VB6 might behave like Notepad in this respect. I don't know enough about VB6 to suggest a fix; maybe preprocess the file somehow to replace all `\n` with `\r\n`?

Comment: VB6 text I/O statements will treat either CR (old Mac standard) or CRLF (Microsoft standard) as line delimiters, but not naked LFs (*NIX).  You could use FSO TextStream I/O, an ADO Stream object, Jet 4.0's Text IISAM, or roll your own reading and splitting data blobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this by doing the following:

1) Copy the text into textpad
2) File/Save As, then select Plain Text
3) Import the generated file as normal

This is a temporary fix.  I will have to automate it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the file comes from a different system. Usually, in a Windows based system, the new line is defined by a `CR` and `LF` characters. In a UNIX environment, new line is defined by a single `LF`.

So your problem is, your incoming file has a bunch of `LF`s without any `CR`s. Your manual approach works because the file is being over written in a windows environment, thus producing `CR LF` combos. So that's the good news. The bad news, there is no easy way to fix this, as far as I know.

You have several approaches that I can think of:

1) if your file is not too large, read the whole file into memory and replace `LF` into `CR LF` or SPLIT by `LF` only and you get your records;

2) if your file is not too large, read one character at a time, when you encounter `LF`, check if previous character is not `CR` and add `CR` in front of `LF` (this method is slow with large files, it is least desirable of all, but is simpler to implement if method 1 and 3 are not feasible)

3) if your file is fixed length and large, read fixed chunks of text. You don't even need to care about new lines

4) if the file is variable length and large and method 2 takes too much time, read a fixed length of text instead. You will have to write a slightly more complex function to split and join these chunks of data, because they may contain 0 to several actual records in it